# What's the best way to use an item-specific ViewModel with Realm?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, realm

I've ported my app to use the Realm database instead of SQLite. However I'm experiencing an issue with the `IRealmCollection` in combination with MVVM.

Let's imagine the following model:

```
public class Item : RealmObject
{
    public string Id { get; }
}
```

The current approach on my `MainViewModel` is this one:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public IRealmCollection<Item> { get; private set; }
}
```

The problem I'm now facing is that the `Item` has specific commands, located in an `ItemViewModel`. I want to use these while keeping the features of the `IRealmCollection`.

The `ItemViewModel`:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public Item Model { get; private set; }
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

There are several methods I've been thinking about, but I've wondered if there's a more simple solution to that:

- Create a custom `ObservableCollection` that subscribes to the Realm
- Use the LINQ `.Select()` extension to create a ViewModel out of the list
- Save the `ItemViewModel` in the Realm and add the `[Ignored]` attribute to each additional property or command
- Move the logic out of the `ItemViewModel` to a separate class (like an `ItemHelper`) and call that from the `MainViewModel`

What's the best and probably most MVVM-like way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your commands and additional properties are simple and can be embedded in the persisted `Item`, I would go with that solution. This may not always work, for example, because RealmObjects are dynamically created upon accessing the index in the collection. E.g.:

```
var collection = realm.All<Item>();
var a = collection.ElementAt(0);
var b = collection.ElementAt(0);
```

will get you different instances for `a` and `b`. This means you can't rely on non-persisted state in your RealmObject inheritors. If this is a dealbreaker, then I would suggest a custom ObservableCollection that wraps `IRealmCollection` and deals with the projections to your ViewModel which can then use composition to expose the RealmObject:

```
public interface IViewModel<T> where T : RealmObject
{
    T Item { get; set; }
}

public class MyObservableCollection<TViewModel, TRealmObject> : IReadOnlyList<TViewModel>, INotifyCollectionChanged
    where TRealmObject : RealmObject
    where TViewModel : IViewModel<TRealmObject>, new()
{
    private readonly IRealmCollection<TRealmObject> _collection;

    public TViewModel this[int index] => Project(_collection[index]);

    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
    {
        add
        {
            UpdateCollectionChangedSubscriptionIfNecessary(isSubscribed: true);
            _collectionChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _collectionChanged -= value;

            UpdateCollectionChangedSubscriptionIfNecessary(isSubscribed: false);
        }
    }

    public MyObservableCollection(IRealmCollection<TRealmObject> collection)
    {
        _collection = collection;
    }

    private TViewModel Project(TRealmObject obj)
    {
        return new TViewModel
        {
            Item = obj
        };
    }

    private void UpdateCollectionChangedSubscriptionIfNecessary(bool isSubscribed)
    {
        if (_collectionChanged == null)
        {
            if (isSubscribed)
            {
                // Subscribe via _collection
            }
            else
            {
                // Unsubscribe via _collection
            }
        }
    }
}
```